# How many Anyons can be allowed in a state

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, research-level, topological-order, anyons

For fermions, a state allows only one fermion to exist . For bosons, there can be infinite number of bosons in one state . But for anyons, how many can a state allow?How do we come to this conclusion?

Comment: I heard that in parastatistics (one of several alternatives to the better known particle statistics models; Bose–Einstein statistics, Fermi–Dirac statistics)  , specifically for parafermions of order p, there can be no more than p fermions in one state

Comment: Try to look up Haldane's "Exclusion statistics". For example these notes by Murthy and Shankar, where the relation between exchange statistics and exclusion statistics is discussed.
https://www.imsc.res.in/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/334/MR120.pdf?sequence=1